# How to make RefreshIndicator work when its child is a PageView

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Stateful Widget which displays list dynamically, the problem is that it is in a BottomNavigationBar with a PageView. Now I can't refresh.

Code -

```dart
Scaffold(
    body: RefreshIndicator(
          child: PageView(
                 children: [Some Widgets with a ListBuilder in them.]
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the child of your `PageView` in a `Scaffold`.

Also, I think you need to make the child of `RefreshIndicator` to scrollable.

```
List<String> pageValue = ['One', '2', 'Three'];

class Test extends State<StatusPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        children: pageValue
            .map((e) => Scaffold(
//                  appBar: AppBar(),
                  body: SafeArea(
                    child: RefreshIndicator(
                      onRefresh: () async {
                        print('hello');
                      },
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text('$e #$index'),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```